# how to pass arguments efficiently (**kwargs in python)

Tags: python, inheritance, keyword-argument

I have a class that inherits from 2 other classes. These are the base classes:

```
class FirstBase(object):
      def __init__(self, detail_text=desc, backed_object=backed_object,
                   window=window, droppable_zone_obj=droppable_zone_obj,
                   bound_zone_obj=bound_zone_object,
                   on_drag_opacity=on_drag_opacity):
          # bla bla bla

class SecondBase(object):
      def __init__(self, size, texture, desc, backed_object, window):
          # bla bla bla
```

And this is the child:

```
class Child(FirstBase, SecondBase):
       """ this contructor doesnt work
       def __init__(self, **kwargs):
          # PROBLEM HERE
          #super(Child, self).__init__(**kwargs)
       """
       #have to do it this TERRIBLE WAY
       def __init__(self, size=(0,0), texture=None, desc="", backed_object=None,
                    window=None, droppable_zone_obj=[], bound_zone_object=[],
                    on_drag_opacity=1.0):
          FirstBase.__init__(self, detail_text=desc, backed_object=backed_object,
                             window=window, droppable_zone_obj=droppable_zone_obj,
                             bound_zone_obj=bound_zone_object,
                             on_drag_opacity=on_drag_opacity)
          SecondBase.__init__(self, size, texture, desc, backed_object, window)
```

I wanted to solve it all nicely with `**kwargs` but when I call the first commented out constructor I get `TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'size'`.

Any ideas how I can make it work with `**kwargs?`

Comment: Upon first reading of this (and not massively in depth I will admit), my first thought is "Are there genuinely two base classes?" There appears to be far too much overlap between the two; ie, `SecondBase` looks like it should be inheriting `FirstBase`, re-implementing some methods and adding others, which would then make it the single base for `Child` and simplify your hierarchy and OO design

Comment: I need to fix them (some code cleanup), but no they are different bases... I marked the solution to this problem

Comment: The currently accepted answer by Diedrich is inaccurate to the extent of my knowledge. I posted my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32135160/2801814

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Your problem is that you only tried to use `super` in the child class.

If you use `super` in the base classes too, then this will work.  Each constructor will "eat" the keyword arguments it takes and not pass them up to the next constructor.  When the constructor for `object` is called, if there are any keyword arguments left over it will raise an exception.

```
class FirstBase(object):
    def __init__(self, detail_text=None, backed_object=None,
                 window=None, droppable_zone_obj=None,
                 bound_zone_obj=None, on_drag_opacity=None, **kwargs):
        super(FirstBase, self).__init__(**kwargs)

class SecondBase(object):
    def __init__(self, size=(0,0), texture=None, desc="",
                 backed_object=None, window=None, **kwargs):
        super(SecondBase, self).__init__(**kwargs)

class Child(FirstBase, SecondBase):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Child, self).__init__(**kwargs)
```

As you can see, it works, except when you pass a bogus keyword argument:

```
>>> Child()
<__main__.Child object at 0x7f4aef413bd0>
>>> Child(detail_text="abc")
<__main__.Child object at 0x7f4aef413cd0>
>>> Child(bogus_kw=123)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "test.py", line 14, in __init__
    super(Child, self).__init__(**kwargs)
  File "test.py", line 5, in __init__
    super(FirstBase, self).__init__(**kwargs)
  File "test.py", line 10, in __init__
    super(SecondBase, self).__init__(**kwargs)
TypeError: object.__init__() takes no parameters
```

Comment: yay I knew it! This is the right solution. I was really wondering about "eating" the keyword arguments :) Nice code sample as well!

Comment: Calling `super()` in the base classes just passes the leftovers in `kwargs` up to the `object` class and dumps them. This is also a poor use of `super()`. I've posted an answer describing more.

Comment: @alavin89: Can you explain why this is a "poor use"?  What makes it a poor use?  It fails in exactly the same way that you would expect: by raising a `TypeError` on unknown keyword arguments.

Comment: @DietrichEpp because you shouldn't have to call super() from a base class. Python does this automatically for anything subclassed from `object`.  All you're doing is repeating this call in order to throw away the arguments in `**kwargs` that aren't being assigned.

Comment: @alavin89: I don't know how anything is being "repeated": the `__init__()` method is called from `Child`, `FirstBase`, `SecondBase`, and by the time it gets to `object`, there are no keyword arguments left.  Nothing is thrown away, every argument is consumed by exactly one function, and any extra arguments raise a `TypeError`.  Perhaps you could demonstrate your approach with some sample code?

Comment: @DietrichEpp if every argument is consumed (as it should be) then there is no need to call super() from the parents, that's my point!

Comment: @alavin89: I am curious here about what you think `super()` does from the parents.  Do you think that `super(FirstBase, self).__init__(**kwargs)` calls `object.__init__(self, **kwargs)`?  Because that's *not* what it does.

Comment: @alavin89: And once again, **PROVIDE SOME SAMPLE CODE** of "every argument being consumed as it should be".  Because I don't know a general way of doing that, not without `super()` and `**kwargs`.

Answer (score 3):

I don't like this solution but you can do this:

```
class FirstBase(object):
  def __init__(self, *args, **kargs):
      kargs.get('karg name', 'default value')
      # bla bla bla

class SecondBase(object):
  def __init__(self, *args, **kargs):
      kargs.get('karg name', 'default value')
      # bla bla bla

class Child(FirstBase, SecondBase):
   def __init__(self, *args, **kargs):
      FirstBase.__init__(self, *args, **kargs)
      SecondBase.__init__(self, *args, **kargs)
```

Comment: it seems to be valid and clean, esp useful when the base class is already being used by others. not sure why no upvote.

Answer (score 1):

Because `FirstBase.__init__` doesn't have the `size` argument. You can either add the `size` argument or add `**kwargs` to `FirstBase.__init__`.

Comment: thanks, this will be it. I just thought that there is some way around it... (I want to keep my Bases contructors with all the parameters to be nicely seen, I just wanted to call the child somehow efficient

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```
class FirstBase(object):
      def __init__(self, detail_text, backed_object, window, droppable_zone_obj, bound_zone_obj, on_drag_opacity):
          # bla bla bla

class SecondBase(object):
      def __init__(self, texture, desc, backed_object, window, size=None):
          # bla bla bla
```

Comment: You cannot specify a keyword argument before a set of positional arguments; your example will raise a SyntaxError exception.

Answer (score 0):

a possible hack (but hacking is bad, remember), is to appeal to the inspect module to obtain the signature of the function that you are going to use:

```
import inspect
#define a test function with two parameters function
def foo(a,b):
    return a+b

#obtain the list of the named arguments
acceptable = inspect.getargspec(f).args

print acceptable
#['a', 'b']

#test dictionary of kwargs
kwargs=dict(a=3,b=4,c=5)

#keep only the arguments that are both in the signature and in the dictionary
new_kwargs = {k:kwargs[k] for k in acceptable if k in kwargs}

#launch with the sanitized dictionary
f(**new_kwargs)
```

This is not a code you should use in production code. If the function refuses some arguments it means that you can obtain the signature reading the code, and passing only the necessary keys. The hack with inspect is far less stable and readable, so use only when you haven't any other way!

Answer (score 0):

Since you have control over the code, the easy way to let yourself just pass around **kwargs the way you want is to add a **kwargs parameter to the __init__ of both base classes, as so:

```
class FirstBase(object):
  def __init__(self, detail_text=desc, backed_object=backed_object,
               window=window, droppable_zone_obj=droppable_zone_obj,
               bound_zone_obj=bound_zone_object,
               on_drag_opacity=on_drag_opacity, **kwargs):
      # bla bla bla

class SecondBase(object):
      def __init__(self, size, texture, desc, backed_object, window, **kwargs):
          # bla bla bla
```

The failure you had encountered is because your base classes only had named parameters, therefore when you pass an unknown name, the bouncer says you're not on my list. By adding **kwargs parameters to the __init__ functions of the base classes, they suddenly allow any arbitrary named value to simply be passed in, which is understandable since, after all, **kwargs is an open ended catch all, nothing of which is named, so how would it know what to exclude? It simply ends up a dictionary of named values in the eyes of the called code, which uses them or doesn't. You could completely ignore **kwargs.

The answer which at the moment of writing is currently accepted as the right one, by Dietrich, confused the essential issue -- it has nothing to do with super() at all, and his correction works simply because **kwargs were added and that opened the door for any arbitrary name.

If you don't have control over the code, you can:

- pass arguments explicitly so as not to unpack *args too long, or **kwargs with unspecified names,
- pop extraneous parameters out of kwargs using the dictionary pop function,
- or you could use this helper meta-function:

  ```
  import inspect

  def anykwarg(function, *args, **kwargs):
      validargs = inspect.getargspec(function).args
      removals = [key for key in kwargs.keys() if key not in validargs]
      for removal in removals:
          del kwargs[removal]
      return function(*args, **kwargs)
  ```

This anykwarg helper could be improved to check for a kwargs parameter and if present not remove any values from the kwargs passed in, and inspect.getargspec used above returns that information. Note, it is okay to del from kwargs in anykwarg because it is not a reference to some dictionary passed in, it is a local dictionary generated from parameters.

Answer (score -1):

You should not have to call `super()` in the base classes, as in [the accepted answer by @Dietrich Epp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13125197/3765905). All you're doing is passing any leftover arguments in `kwargs` up to the `object` base class, where they're thrown away; this is sloppy.

When you do `super(ChildClass, self).__init__(foo, bar, **kwargs)`, the super class(es) of `ChildClass` must expect **all** the arguments `foo`, `bar`, and `**kwargs`. So in your case, getting the error `TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'size'` implies your parent classes of `Child` either don't have `size` or don't have `**kwargs` in their `__init__()` methods.

When your `super()` call goes to each of `Firstbase` and `Secondbase`, their constructors will try and unpack `**kwargs` into their keyword arguments. **Everything in `**kwargs` needs to go somewhere.** Anything leftover (i.e. not specified by a keyword argument), like `size`, will raise your TypeError, unless there is another `**kwargs` for the leftovers to go into.

Comment: This is factually incorrect: the `object` constructor does not accept any arguments, so none of the arguments will get thrown away.  I believe I demonstrated this in the bottom half of my answer.  I don't see what is sloppy about the method I presented: you can specify only the keyword arguments that are explicitly accepted by a constructor, other keyword arguments raise errors.

Comment: Actually, I'm a little confused by this answer.  Is there a solution in there somewhere?  It looks like this is only an explanation of the problem, rather than a solution.  Perhaps some short sample code could help?

Comment: @DietrichEpp yes it's an explanation to help others understand the passing of arguments in mixin constructors. A solution would follow from my point that "everything in `**kwargs` needs to go somewhere"; i.e. all the arguments initially in `**kwargs` from the child need to be used in the parent constructors.

Comment: But, that's exactly what my solution does.  Every argument in `**kwargs` is used by one of the parent constructors.  The `object` constructor accepts no arguments, so it raises an error if there are any arguments left over.

Comment: But please... provide some sample code.  I'm not sure exactly how you would translate this into code.  That's the whole point.